# python-curses doesn't register instr()

Tags: python, input, terminal, curses, instr

I'm writing a doodle-jump terminal game for which I need to know whether or not the player has hit an obstacle. For that I'm using the **instr()** function to tell me if an obstacle was hit. But it doesn't register and also during debugging it doesn't activate the if-clause. Heres the python-code to my while playing function (the weird string is the player):

```
def play(difficulty, resize_w, resize_h):
    playing = True
    current_x, current_y = 10, resize_h//2
    env = create_env(resize_h, resize_w)
    counter = 0
    while playing:   
        counter += 1
        stdscr.clear()
        print_env(env,counter)
        
        stdscr.refresh()
        stdscr.addstr(current_y,current_x,"o/00\o")


        if stdscr.instr(current_y+1, current_x,1) == "=":
            stdscr.addstr(5,5,"Yes")
        else:
            stdscr.addstr(5,5,"NO")

        stdscr.timeout(60)
        inp = stdscr.getch()
        if inp == curses.KEY_LEFT and current_x > 0:
            current_x -= 2 
            move_left(current_x, current_y)
        elif inp == curses.KEY_RIGHT and current_x < (resize_w-6): 
            current_x += 2
            move_right(current_x, current_y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdscr.instr` will return [a bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.instr) -- bytes objects are never equal to strings (`str` type) in python 3+

try:

```py
        if stdscr.instr(current_y+1, current_x,1) == b"=":
```

Comment: thank you it works now :) Kind of odd that I couldn't find anything about that on the internet... Probably didn't look long enough

Comment: if you run `python -b` or `python -bb` it will show warnings for when you're comparing bytes and strings incorrectly